# Colour a button blue, with help of css

Tags: html, css

I just want to colour a button in webpage. The html section of the web page is given below.From my understanding its single button from a group of adjacent button.

```
enter code here
<div id="moderationbuttons">
  <div class="buttonlist floatbottom" id="moderationbuttons_strip">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li>
        <a class="button_strip_0"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to know how to select button_strip_0. Dont know how to do it with two classes in an id??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of zero research effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do

.html with CSS

```
<style>
#moderationbuttons .buttonlist ul.nav 
{
    list-style-type:none;
}
#moderationbuttons .button_strip_0 
{
    padding:5px;
    background-color: #0874d1;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px
}
</style>

<div id="moderationbuttons">
  <div class="buttonlist floatbottom" id="moderationbuttons_strip">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li>
        <a class="button_strip_0">
          <i class="fa fa-0 fa-fw"></i>
          Hello
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i will try this..but can you suggest a css version of this,which is more important for me.

Comment: Answer is updated @Prototype

Comment: I tried the above code but it somehow now working. what bothers me is missing of id in the css @Efe Omoregie

Comment: Why not? Did you add the css in an external file and link it to your page?

Comment: See updated answer above

Comment: Thanks a lot @Efe Omoregie . Its worked ...actually its a mistake from my part. Your code works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**The art of asking Stack Overflow Questions**

While this is irrelevant to your actual question, use this as advice for asking questions in the future. Before you ask a question about a problem in code, first search or read a tutorial on how to do the given task. Make sure you research VERY thoroughly, before asking the question. Your question can be very easily answered if you had gone through the trouble to use Google. See reference for asking future questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?).

*Anyway...* back to your question.
To do this, take your individual `li` element, and in a seperate CSS file, which should have been linked by you in the `<head>` tag of your html document as follows:
`<link type="text/css" rel="stylsheet" href="MY_FILE_NAME.css"/>`, do the following:

```css
.button_strip_0 {
   background-color:red; /*Or whatever other hex color you choose*/
   color:white; /*Color the text in the element, Or whatever other hex color you choose*/
}
```

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. My area of expertise is not css or html. It will helpful if you tell me what exactly i have to add in my css.

Comment: The snippet that I have posted is exactly what you have to put in your CSS. What exact rules you want to apply can only be evident from your question. For example, to say, change the background color of the button, you can change the background color to one of the xss colors that is accepted, or one of the thousands of hex colors there are. The one other thing I have to say, is take a html and css tutorial online before continuing. The website I used is called [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/). This will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
.button_strip_0 {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice

Comment: Thanks kevnk for the replay, i tested the code but some how not working. I not an expert in css or html.